# Formal name for a shape that has one or more interior holes

Tags: geometry

I'm looking for the formal mathematical name for shapes that have one or more interior holes / punched out sections.

Comment: You're thinking of a painter's palette, possibly with multiple holes? If so, I've never come across a widely-used name, though topologists and complex analysts sometimes speak of a _multiply-connected plane region_. Algebraic geometers speak of _multiply-punctured curves_, but that generally has a subtly different meaning (the complex plane with a discrete set of points removed).

Comment: related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number (see geometric interpretation)

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of a word with the gravitas of "Closed Shape" or "Irregular Polygon" but applying to this situation. I was under the impression there was a standard term for this but I'm starting to think no.

Comment: I agree, *multiply-connected* is the most standard name, going back to the 19th century (I think, Jordan).